# get PID by name

Tags: regular-expression, process, ps

I'm running an autopilot on a closed environment running Linux, and I've got a kernel thread whose priority I need to change. I'd prefer not to patch the kernel for this. This thread is created early on startup when the SPI driver probes its hardware, and named spi0. I can break this problem into two parts, I need help getting the PID of the thread named [spi0], and using `chrt` to mark it as SCHED_FIFO and set priority accordingly is easy enough once I have the PID.

```
$ ps -ef | grep '\[spi0\]'
root       203     2  2 Aug28 ?        00:59:19 [spi0]
```

Comment: Use `pgrep` instead.

Comment: and `pgrep` manpage has also an example on what you are trying to do: `renice +4 $(pgrep chrome)` (replace chrome with your spi0, and `chrt` instead of `renice`

Answer (score 1):

While searching tags on Unix stack exchange, I found `pidof` and `pgrep`.  These have a much simpler output for capturing in a shell script:

```bash
$ pidof -s spi0
203
```

or, to get an exact match against the process name and returning the PID of the *oldest* matching process, using `pgrep`,

```bash
$ pgrep -x -o spi0
203
```

So the full scheduler adjustment becomes:

```bash
$ sudo chrt -f -p 10 "$(pidof -s spi0)"
$ sudo chrt -p "$(pidof -s spi0)"
pid 203's current scheduling policy: SCHED_FIFO
pid 203's current scheduling priority: 10
```